# java.lang.RuntimeException: Must set 'realm' in config

Tags: java, spring, keycloak

I created a spring micro-service and I'm trying verify a jwt token created using keycloak.

My application.yaml file contains the following keycloak property:

```
 keycloak:
    enabled: true
    auth-server-url: http://localhost:8080/auth}
    realm: another_realm
    realm-key: another_key
    resource: ping-pong
    credentials.secret: another_secret
    principal-attribute: blue
    public-client: false
    ssl-required: external
    cors: true
    autodetect-bearer-only: true
    use-resource-role-mappings: false
    expose-token: true
    security-constraints:
               - authRoles: [ 'ping_pong_user' ]
        securityCollections:
               - name: api
        patterns: [ '/api/*' ]
```

My pom file contains the keycloak dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I'm trying to call my api resources the application returns an error:

```
    2020-11-30 10:07:03.101 ERROR 12336 --- [.0-18090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing /api/save

java.lang.RuntimeException: Must set 'realm' in config
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.internalBuild(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:57) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-11.0.3.jar:11.0.3]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:202) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-11.0.3.jar:11.0.3]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.resolve(KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.java:41) ~[keycloak-spring-boot-adapter-core-11.0.3.jar:11.0.3]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakSpringConfigResolverWrapper.resolve(KeycloakSpringConfigResolverWrapper.java:40) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-11.0.3.jar:11.0.3]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext.resolveDeployment(AdapterDeploymentContext.java:89) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-11.0.3.jar:11.0.3]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler.preflightCors(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:100) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-11.0.3.jar:11.0.3]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler.handleRequest(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:75) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-11.0.3.jar:11.0.3]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:177) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-11.0.3.jar:11.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_241]
```

Any clues?

Comment: Hi did you mange to solve you problem?

Comment: Yes. It was an api gateway config issue

Comment: Nice to hear so it had nothing to with any of the answers ? :) Then I think you can just delete the question

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your config file? I hope you have used the spring keycloak adapter.
You can also check if the realm is created in your Keycloak UI